# Action Button to AJAX request in php

Tags: php, jquery, ajax

How can i hide notification with ajax? I want to press button and pass to delete my notification with id 5.

```
if(isset($_POST['notification']))
{
  $id = $_GET['hidenotification'];
  $QUERY = "UPDATE `Notifications` SET `ActiveNotification` = 0 WHERE `id` = '$id'";
  $connection->query($QUERY);
}
```

$notification_id = 5;

```
<a href='#' onClick='HideNotification($notification_id);'>Hide this notification</a>

function HideNotification(id)
{
 jQuery.ajax({
  type: "POST",
  url: "index.php",
  data: 'hidenotification='+id,
  cache: false,
  success: function(response)
    {
      alert("Notification deleted.");
    }
 });
}
```

My problem is when i press button to request hiding notification, my table is not updated ..

Comment: `if(isset($_POST['notification']))` this is never true

Comment: You are passing variable name 'hidenotification' but you were check if(isset($_POST['notification'])){ } this is never TRUE , change this to if(isset($_POST['hidenotification'])){ }

Comment: its not working..

Answer (score 1):

You can just hide it with Jquery's `hide` function:

```
<a class="notification" href='#' onClick='HideNotification($notification_id);'>Hide this notification</a>

function HideNotification(id)
{
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: 'hidenotification='+id,
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
            $('.notification').hide()
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: I want to query in mysql not only in page.

Comment: No, when i click on button my notification is not hiding, even after refresh page.

Comment: Did the `alert ` in your original question ever fire? Is the ajax being executed? Do you have any errors in the console?

Comment: $('.notification').hide() should also work. Did you add the `notification` class to the anchor?

Answer (score 1):

Simply If you want to hide your button after response get.

try bellow code...

**Html code**

```
$notification_id = 5;

<a href='javascript:void(0);' class='notification' id="<?=$notification_id?>">Hide this notification</a>
```

**Jquery code**

```
$(".notification").click(function(){
    var obj=$(this);
    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "index.php",
        data: {hidenotification: obj.attr('id')},
        cache: false,
        success: function(response)
        {
           obj.hide()// if you want to only hide button
           obj.remove() //if you want to remove button
        }
    });
});
```

**Php code**

```
if(isset($_POST['hidenotification']))
{
  $id = $_POST['hidenotification'];
  $QUERY = "UPDATE `Notifications` SET `ActiveNotification` = 0 WHERE `id` = '$id'";
  $connection->query($QUERY);
}
```

Comment: My problem is when i press button to request hiding notification, my table is not updated ..

Answer (score 0):

```
function HideNotification(id)
{
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php",
data: {hidenotification:id},
cache: false,
success: function(response)
{
  alert("Notification deleted.");
}
});
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use following code for hide notification and update in database table via ajax php. And use $_REQUEST OR $_POST if you used post method in ajax.

```
<a class="notification" id="<?php echo $notification_id;?>" href='#' onClick="HideNotification('<?php echo $notification_id;?>');">Hide this notification</a>


function HideNotification(id)
{
jQuery.ajax({
type: "POST",
url: "index.php",
data: {hidenotification:id},
cache: false,
success: function(response)
{
jQuery('#'+id).hide();
}
});
}
```

Comment: Can you let me know what is error ? Are you sure jquery lib is include  ?

Answer (score 0):

just keep

```
$id = $_POST['hidenotification'];
  $QUERY = "UPDATE `Notifications` SET `ActiveNotification` = 0 WHERE `id` = '$id'";
  $connection->query($QUERY);
```

**instead**.Remove `if(isset($_POST['notification']))` and use post.